# SQL Server ContainsTable not returning result with word that start with "N"

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I want to make a query to retrieve people with NEAR syntax. When I search whatever text that contains letter N in second word, the result is always empty.

I have two people Ricardo registred on table, "Ricardo Mova" and "Ricardo Nova". If a search 'Ricardo NEAR "Mova*"' it's OK, but not for 'Ricardo NEAR 'Nova*'

**EDIT**

- 4 records (Ricardo Nova, Ricardo Novais, Ricardo Novo, Ricardo Nunes)
- query 'Ricardo NEAR 'N*'
- result shows just "Ricardo Novais" and "Ricardo Nunes".

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntitySearch](
    [IdEntity] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Accessibility] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Document] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Phone2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Birthdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Gender] [int] NULL,
    [IsAct] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Discriminator] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.EntitySearch] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IdEntity] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =     OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Catalog**

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG main_catalog;
```

**Full Index**

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.EntitySearch 
        (       [Name] 
            Language[Brazilian],  
                [Document]
            Language[Brazilian],
                [Email]
            Language[Brazilian], 
                [Phone]
            Language[Brazilian],
                [Phone2]
            Language[Brazilian] )  
KEY INDEX [PK_dbo.EntitySearch] ON main_catalog;
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT top 10
    FT_TBL.[IdEntity]
    ,FT_TBL.[Name]
    ,FT_TBL.[Accessibility]
    ,FT_TBL.[Document]
    ,FT_TBL.[Email]
    ,FT_TBL.[Phone]
    ,FT_TBL.[Phone2]
    ,FT_TBL.[Birthdate]
    ,FT_TBL.[Gender]
    ,FT_TBL.[IsAct]
    ,FT_TBL.[Discriminator]
    FROM [EntitySearch] AS FT_TBL INNER JOIN  
    CONTAINSTABLE ([EntitySearch], [Name], 'Ricardo NEAR "Nova*"' ) AS KEY_TBL  
    ON FT_TBL.[IdEntity] = KEY_TBL.[KEY]  
    WHERE
        FT_TBL.[IsAct] = 1 
    and FT_TBL.[Discriminator] = 2
    and KEY_TBL.RANK > 10  
    ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC, FT_TBL.[Name]
```

I expect that show 1 record, but none is showed. Thanks!

**EDIT: WORKAROUND**

I dropped and recriated the full text index with PORTUGUESE language. The problem has gone, so I guess the "bug" is on Brazilian language for index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a BUG.

Each langue has your self stop word list, which means that some words are irrelevant for the index search.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.fulltext_system_stopwords 
WHERE language_id = 1046 --Brazilian language ID
```

So, in my case, I did an algorithm that corrects the search query before sending.